# PHP Printer function with html output

Tags: php, printing

```
<?php 
$printer = "PrinterName"; 
if($ph = printer_open($printer)) 
{ 

   $fh = fopen("file.txt", "rb"); 
   $content = fread($fh, filesize("file.txt")); 
   fclose($fh); 

   printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW"); 
   printer_write($ph, $content); 
   printer_close($ph); 
} 

?>
```

This is the code that I use to print a .txt format file by choosing printer using PHP.
Where should I modify so that I can print a .php page with HTML output ?
Any suggestion? Please help me

Comment: remove `)` in first line `$printer = "PrinterName");` and make it `$printer = "PrinterName";` and to print any other page see answer

Comment: Sorry, i post the wrong code..now i remove the ), actually the coding is error free, i just want to change the .txt file to html output, if i change the file.txt to file.php, the output is the source code and not the output ..

Comment: There is still no printering system (or printer enabled logic) to print html directly in a way that makes sense. You have to prepare the markup and turn it into some other format first. Something like pdf format can make sense, if you have a good printing system (or good printers with an embedded system) available that can print such format directly without requiring additional software. Take a look around, also a "headless browser" might be of help. but there is no really reliable solution AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

to print any page modify your code as follows

```
$page = "http://your_domain_name/filename.php";
print_page($page);

function print_page($page)
{
    $printer = "PrinterName"); 
    if($ph = printer_open($printer)) 
    { 


       $content = get_file_contents($page); 

       printer_set_option($ph, PRINTER_MODE, "RAW"); 
       printer_write($ph, $content); 
       printer_close($ph); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: And you are sure that a normal printer is able to interpret html markup and print a page layout? That would be an interesting feature, especially with embedded pictures and the like... ;-)

Comment: it will print out the source code and the output. Can it print out only the output ?

Comment: Is it working? I guess it will print HTML source ie. `<html> <head> ...bla bla bla..` instead visual output rendered by browser. I'm also facing same problem